# FirebaseAuth UI Google SignIn Enable cookies on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, user-interface, authentication, firebase-authentication

Using the FirebaseAuthUI when signing in with Google on an iOS app, it redirected to a page saying:

> "You've reached this page because we have detected that cookies are
>   disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot
>   display properly if cookies are disabled. Please enable cookies and
>   retry the operations or go back in your browser"

Is that normal behavior? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Settings, Safari, Block all cookies Turn Off and wait like an hour.